# Two cards are drawn without replacement. Find a probability when Queens are drawn.

Tags: probability, card-games

Standard deck of 52 cards. 
2 cards are dealt WITHOUT replacement. 
What is the probability that both cards are Queens given that one of them is the Queen of Clubs.

Conditional Probability.

P(Two Queens | Queen of Clubs) = P(Two Queens AND Queen of Clubs) / P(Queen of Clubs)

P(Two cards of the same face value) = (4/52)(3/51) = 1/221

Stuck.

Comment: Thank you Ross, I meant to indicate two cards of the same face value, i.e., two Kings, or two Queens, or two sevens, etc. I updated the problem definition.

Comment: Given one of the cards is Queen of Clubs, you have 51 ways to choose the second card, and 3 of them are Queens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $51$ two-card hands that contain the queen of clubs.  Of these, $3$ contain another queen.  Hence, the desired probability is

> $$\frac{3}{51} = \frac{1}{17}$$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.